# "80% of what I listen to is/are K-pop groups"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? The "80% of [it]" part is what has me confused.

a. 80% of what I listen to is K-pop groups.

b. 80% of what I listen to are K-pop groups.

Should I perhaps just say "K-pop groups are 80% of what I listen to"?

Comment: Either way, it's clumsy-sounding. I suppose I'd consider 'is' better, reading 'what' as referring to 'the music', which is a mass noun here. But 'K-pop groups' doesn't match 'the music I listen to' like 'ska' say would do.  'When it comes to music, I listen to K-pop groups 80% of the time' removes one problem but still doesn't sound brilliant.

Comment: This may have been answered before. Please research this site.

Comment: Just invert it: "K-pop groups are 80% of what I listen to." (Although if this statement is true, you really need to broaden your taste in music.)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better say **"80% of what I listen to is K-pop"** because basically it's not about the groups but the kind of music you listen to. 
Of course there are other ways to express your idea. For example, *80% of the music I listen to is made by K-pop groups*.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Enguroo's answer, and their suggestion to omit the noun "groups" but if push comes to shove, and you don't want to leave out the *countable* noun, choose b.)

> b.) 80% of what I listen to are K-pop groups.

The percentage refers to numerable units, with a little rewording we see why the verb must be plural

> 80% of the **groups** I listen to **are** K-pop

However, it's a bit awkward to start a sentence with a number, a fraction or a percentage. @Edwin's [solution](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437743/80-of-what-i-listen-to-is-are-k-pop-groups#comment1050906_437743) is preferable,(“… I listen to K-pop groups 80% of the time”) otherwise leave out the percentage and be less specific, e.g.

> Nearly everything I listen to **is** K-pop **music**.

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but as for avoiding starting a sentence with a number or percentage, isn't it more typical of scientific writing? I know that even in this kind of writing it's possible to start a sentence with a percentage if it is spelled out. But the original sentence about K-pop doesn't seem to be so formal.

Comment: @Enguroo I said starting a sentence with a fraction or a percentage was a bit awkward, I didn't say it must be avoided. I agree the original sentence is informal but I'd still prefer Edwin's version.